# JS exports var, if it has no value I get no method exists, if it has value its ok

Tags: javascript, object

I need to access and array from another file in my nodejs/socket.io project(not relevant to this question however), index.js:

```
exports.rooms = function(){
    if(username < usernames.length){
        return usernames;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In admin.js

I use:

```
var index = require('./index.js');
```

The problem is if the exports.rooms function has no values I get the following error:

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'rooms'
```

Now the function is there it just has no values... I have tried the following function but i get the same error:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There may be undefined variable. But your code is checking for property only.

Comment: after some further debugging the isEmpty function seems broken, if I console.log('something'); just after for(var prop in obj) It doesn't write to terminal.